# Check_boxes from formtastic not working with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mongoid, formtastic

I'm working in a form for adding news.
So I want the user tu choose from the available categories
using checkboxes.
But formtastic keep printing weird stuff.

pd. I'm using active-admin and all my resources are working properly

My relationship is:
News has and belongs_to_many categories.

This how I'm trying to print

```
<%=e.label :categorias %>
<%=e.check_boxes :categoria_ids, Hash[Categoria.all.map {|ca| [ca.nombre, ca.id]}]%>
```

If I change check_boxes to select, it works perfectly. But it isn't what I'm looking for.

Here what I get back.
Categorias [#", label="Educativo">, #", label="Música">, #", label="Deportivos">]

Answer (score 0):

```
<%=e.check_boxes :categorias, Hash[Categoria.all.map {|ca| [ca.nombre, ca.id]}]%>
```

Comment: Thanks!but still not working here what I'm getting back.
[#<struct MetaSearch::CheckBox="<input id=..."